# Worth getting thermal paste? Ran 20 youtube videos and got high 70 (degree C) CPU temperature and 80% RAM Usage

Tags: performance, thermal-paste

CPU: 2.2GHz

RAM: 6G

OS: Win7

Model: Samsung NP700Z5BH

Usage: Image Processing

`#`Is it worth upgrading to 8G RAM too?

[image: performance test photo]
<sup>click to enlarge</sup>

Comment: Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: There is no such thing as a “Samsung NP70Z5BH”. Please clarify what you’re talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't slept well and forgot a 0. Here: [http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP700Z5B-W01UB-specs](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP700Z5B-W01UB-specs)

Comment: I see. I suggest you move your RAM issue to another question. In this new question, please provide a screenshot of Resource Monitor’s memory view.

Comment: why would anyone run 20 youtube videos at once? 0_0

Comment: I'm waiting for the RAM to warm-up to take the screen-shot.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek He didn’t say he played them all at once. ;)

Comment: @FreedomToWin That’s not the memory view and that’s not a new question. Please keep separate concerns separate. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your laptop](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP700Z5B-W01UB-specs) has an [Intel i7-2675QM processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/53470/Intel-Core-i7-2675QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz). This is a mobile CPU rated at up to 100°C. As such the temperatures are perfectly normal.

I have a similar mobile CPU that reaches up to 90°C when gaming.

Comment: I didn't even think to check the rating.  Also, I didn't know Tjunction was the max temp rating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting Thermal Paste will surely not solve your problem. If you upgrade your cooling, i.e., get liquid cooling or add additional fans, only then the heat will dissipate properly.

Your motherboard probably has 2 RAM slots (1X2GB & 1X4GB) and so when you buy RAM, you'll have to replace the 2GB one. Also make sure that the RAM is dual-channeled (i.e., having two RAM boards of the same type) so that your computer can read and write to the memory at the same time.